# Q: Foursquare venue search - omit a sub category id

Tags: api, foursquare

Is there an easy way to omit a category id from appearing in a venue search? For example the Food category has multiple sub categories;

- Food

  - American Restaurant
  - Asian Restaurant

    - Japanese Restaurant

      - Sushi bar
    - Chinese Restaurant

etc etc

Say you are interested in ALL of the sub categories under Food except maybe two of them. Rather than having to form a url string with some 500+ sub category IDs without the 2 you do not want, is there a way to use the single main category ID for food with a parameter to **omit** one or two sub categories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to omit a specific category. If it's only 2 categories that should be omitted out of the ~500 food categories you could probably add that logic to the client.